# GWT Editor Framework, how to implement an effective reuse of the editor

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-editors

In many cases I have the same panel which edits a set of properties that are common to different DTOs.
So I want to have this panels defined only once and reuse so I came up with the following implementation for one of them:

```
public class IdentificationPanel<M> extends Panel implements Editor<M> {

   BusinessUnitField businessUnit;

   OperationCodeField operationCode;

   OperationNumber operationNumber;

   ...........
}
```

So I will use the IdentificationPanel with different DTOs depending on the Models I will need to edit.
For example I have:

```
public class ExampleTrans01 extends ModelDTO {

    private ExampleTrans01Header header;

    .......
}

public class ExampleTrans02 extends ModelDTO {

   private ExampleTrans02Header header;

   .....
}

public class ExampleTrans01Header extends ModelDTO {
   private Integer businessUnit;

   private String operationCode;

   private Long operationNumber;

   .......
   // Setters & Getters
}

public class ExampleTrans02Header extends ModelDTO {
   private Integer businessUnit;

   private String operationCode;

   private Long operationNumber;

   .......
   // Setters & Getters
}
```

So in the implementation of the editors for the 2 classes I need to edit I will have:

```
public class ExampleTrans01Editor extends Panel implements Editor<ExampleTrans01> {

   @Path("header")
   IdentificationPanel<ExampleTrans01Header> identification;

   .......
}

public class ExampleTrans02Editor extends Panel implements Editor<ExampleTrans02> {

   @Path("header")
   IdentificationPanel<ExampleTrans02Header> identification;

   ........
}
```

When I try to compile this, GWT complains because it said that there is no constructor for the IdentificationPanel_businessUnit_Context class with the class ExampleTrans02Header as parent when it was generating the Delegate.

I know I maybe get rid of the problem by extending IdentificationPanel, like:

```
public class ExampleTrans01Identification extends IdentificationPanel<ExampleTrans01Header> {
    // Nothing interesting to do here
}

public class ExampleTrans02Identification extends IdentificationPanel<ExampleTrans02Header> {
   // Nothing interesting to do here
}
```

And then use this classes instead the parameterized, but that solution seems to be a little nasty because those classes will not have any other use.

So the question is, are there any other way of implement this case? I was wondering that this should be a very common use case, but I couldn't found much info about it.

On a side note I may said that I new to Editor Framework so maybe I was interpreting something wrong, I will appreciated if you could put me in the right direction.

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and there's no other known workaround.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6016

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas, hope this can be fixed soon!

Comment: Should be included in GWT 2.5, to be released before the end of the quarter (read: in time for Google I/O)